# How to update data on a webpage using Flask?

Tags: python, flask

I am trying to call a class method which then returns a list such as `['Station: 0', 'Place1: 2', 'Extension12: 4']` and then display this list in flask webpage. My problem is, When the list is updated by the `call_agent.Main_Agent()` method, to something like this `['Station: 0', 'Place2: 2', 'Extension12: 4']` the webpage does not update the records. I was wondering what could be the problem

Here is my code below:

```
file_path = '../SAPS_Forecast/Dockets.txt'

app = Flask(__name__)

call_agent = UtilityAgent(file_path)

path_sequence = call_agent.Main_Agent()

@app.route('/forecast.html')
def My_Forecast():
    return render_template('./forecast.html', post=path_sequence)
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Specifically, what does "the webpage does not update the records" mean? Does refreshing the page help? Are you expecting the page to update automatically, without refreshing?

Comment: Hi Chris.The webpage only displays the first call of the method, which is this list `['Station: 0', 'Place1: 2', 'Extension12: 4']`, even after I refresh. I would like that the webpage gets updated with a new list when I refresh the page. Thank you

Comment: Crozier, in your Flask app, you should probably consider every indivudal request as a separate invocation of your program. Are you storing the state somewhere external (such as a database)? If its just updating a python variable, taht would be the expoected behavior.

Comment: Alternatively, if what you mean is "I changed the code but the website didn't change", you need to restart your application, and in case your browser is caching the GET request, do a hard refresh in your browser

Comment: Hi Paul. So the best possible way would be to store the state externally? Thanks. This clarifies things

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Even I used to get the same error. What I did was saved the data in an external database like sqlite or MySql and in the route function, I retrieve the data directly from the database. And then after reloading, the web-page updates.